# ActivityResultLauncher not working with fragment?

Tags: kotlin, permissions, fragment, gallery

I'm writing an app using Kotlin.
I'am using ActivityResultLauncher for get permission. I can use ActivityResultLauncher on Activity clearly but when I try to get permission on fragment with ActivityResultLauncher, the app goint to background without getting any error. I will put my code below. Please help me :)

```
private var selectedPictureUri: Uri? = null
private lateinit var permissionLauncherForGallery: ActivityResultLauncher<String>
private lateinit var activityResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>


override fun populateUI(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setClickListener()
        registerLauncher()
    }



private fun selectMedia() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        //request permission
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                this@WriteUsActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            )
        ) {
            Snackbar.make(
                mBinding!!.root,
                "Permission needed for Gallery",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
            ).setAction("Give Permission") {
                permissionLauncherForGallery.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            }.show()
        } else {
            permissionLauncherForGallery.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        }
    } else {
        val intentToGallery =
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        activityResultLauncher.launch(intentToGallery)
    }
}



private fun registerLauncher() {
        activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                val intentFromResult = result.data
                if (intentFromResult != null) {
                    selectedPictureUri = intentFromResult.data

                    if (selectedPictureUri != null) {  
                        mBinding?.ivPhoto?.visibility= View.VISIBLE
                        mBinding?.ivPhoto?.setImageURI(selectedPictureUri)
                    } else { 
                        val bundle = result.data!!.extras
                        val bitmap = bundle?.get("data")
                        mBinding?.ivPhoto?.setImageBitmap(bitmap as Bitmap)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        permissionLauncherForGallery =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { result ->
                if (result) {
                    //permission granted
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            this,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        val intentToGallery =
                            Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                        activityResultLauncher.launch(intentToGallery)

                    }
                } else {
                    //permission denied
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permisson needed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }

    }



private fun setClickListener() {
    mBinding?.apply {
        btnPhoto.setOnClickListener {
            selectMedia()
        }

        btnPhoto2.setOnClickListener {
            this@WriteUsActivity.toast("Pick Second Photo")
        }

        btnSend.setOnClickListener {
            this@WriteUsActivity.toast("Save")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `populateUI()`?

Comment: @ArpitShukla It's my base class fun for UI. I use this fun like OnCreate.